# Finding all solutions to $cx \leq |x|$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

I'm looking find all $c \in \mathbb{R}$ that solve the inequality:

$cx \leq |x|$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

I know the solution should be $-1 \leq c \leq 1$, but don't know how I am supposed to get there.

Could someone walk me through how to navigate the absolute value when there is an x outside the absolute value?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan You can't just square inequality both sides like that. For example, $-2\leq 1$, but $(-2)^2=4>1$

Comment: @Jakobian True but you could easily get around that with: "assume $x>0$. Then $cx\leq \left| x\right| \Rightarrow cx^2\leq \left| x\right|x \Rightarrow cx^2\leq x^2\Rightarrow c\leq 1$.". And then similarly consider the case for $x<0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation you want to solve is equivalent to the system of the two equations :
$$\forall x > 0, cx \leq x  \quad \text{ and } \quad \forall x < 0, cx \leq -x $$

Obviously, the solutions of the first equation are the all the $c \leq 1$, and the solutions of the second one are all the $c \geq -1$.

So, the solutions of your equation are all the $-1 \leq c\leq 1$.

Comment: Thats great! Could you explain why the solution of the following inequality is $c \geq -1$ ?
$cx \leq -x$, for all $x < 0$

Comment: Just divide the two members of the second inequality by $x$ : you get $c \geq -1$ (don't forget to reverse the sense of the inequality, because you divide by a negative number !).

Comment: That's huge! That's the step I missed. Thanks so much. 

Do you know if I can always use this procedure of separating the absolute value into two inequalities that need to be simultaneously satisfied? (one for when the x in abs(x) is negative, and the other for when it is positive)

Comment: By definition, the absolute value of $x$ is equal to $x$ if $x \geq 0$ and is equal to $-x$ if $x \leq 0$. So you can always treat these two cases separately, to get rid of the absolute value !

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases to consider: $x>0$ and $x<0$.
If $x<0$, then $|x|=-x$.
So $cx\leq|x|\rightarrow c\geq\frac{|x|}{x}=\frac{-x}{x}=-1$

Now consider what happens for $x>0$, see if you can come to the solution $c\leq1$

Comment: c < -1 is incorrect, for any negative x < -1

Comment: @Uq'''12wn1F12u2x3uW31H1JBk9m the conclusion is that $c\geq-1$ for $x<0$.  I do not understand your comment

Comment: Whoops, my mistake! Thank you